# GS4 - Stuck in a bootloop on stock ROM

Tags: adb, samsung, boot-loop, stock-rom

SGH-I337 I got recently is stuck in a bootloop. Itll post and then attempt booting and stay on the screen forever. As this phone is completely stock and never touched so usb debugging is not enabled. Factory resetting does nothing, the phone will not wipe the cache (it attempts then errors out and restarts itself). Ive tried flashing TWRP via odin but the bootloader is locked. Trying to use ADB logcat does not seem to work. What route should I take from here?

Answer (score -1):

Run `adb logcat` during boot, record the output and post it here / try to find the cause of the boot loop.